# Is 202 Accepted an acceptable response to an http patch?

Tags: rest, http, http-patch

I need to do asynchronous updates to a resource.  Is there definitive statement on whether or not a 202 Accepted is an appropriate response to a PATCH?

The official documentation [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789), never mentions a 202, and appears to be assuming that resource changes due to a PATCH are made synchronously, but it never makes a definite statement.

What is the appropriate schematics for the PATCH action?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see why returning a 202 is bad. While there is not explicit mention of using `202`, the spec does hint to it in the example.

> Successful PATCH response to existing text file:
>
> HTTP/1.1 204 No Content    Content-Location: /file.txt    ETag:
>   "e0023aa4f"
>
> The 204 response code is used because the response does not carry a
>   message body (which a response with the 200 code would have).  Note
>   that **other success codes could be used** as well.

`202` is a success code and it's definition does not prohibit it's use in a `PATCH`.

> 10.2.3 202 Accepted
>
> The request has been accepted for processing, but the processing has
>   not been completed. The request might or might not eventually be acted
>   upon, as it might be disallowed when processing actually takes place.
>   There is no facility for re-sending a status code from an asynchronous
>   operation such as this.
>
> The 202 response is intentionally non-committal. Its purpose is to
>   allow a server to accept a request for some other process (perhaps a
>   batch-oriented process that is only run once per day) without
>   requiring that the user agent's connection to the server persist until
>   the process is completed. The entity returned with this response
>   SHOULD include an indication of the request's current status and
>   either a pointer to a status monitor or some estimate of when the user
>   can expect the request to be fulfilled.

As long as you patch atomically and the async request does not leave the resource in a half-patched state, this should be good.